# Number of input neurons in a LSTM Autoencoder

Tags: neural-networks, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, autoencoders

My training data of shape `(2110, 5, 29)`. When building a LSTM Autoencoder can the number of LSTM cells in my first LSTM layer be more than dimensions of the original input (i.e. 29)?

Is it always the case that having more input neurons than features will lead to the network just copying the input value to the remaining neurons?

So do we prefer this:

```py
num_observations = X.shape[0] # 2110
num_features = X.shape[2] # 29
time_steps = 5
input_shape = (time_steps, num_features)

# number of LSTM cells = 100
model = LSTM(100, return_sequences=True, input_shape=input_shape)
...
```

over this?

```py
num_observations = X.shape[0] # 2110
num_features = X.shape[2] # 29
time_steps = 5
input_shape = (time_steps, num_features)

# number of LSTM cells = 25 
model = LSTM(25, return_sequences=True, input_shape=input_shape)
...
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "cell" and "feature"? Typically, I think of cell as a unit of time while feature represents something specific about that unit of time. For instance, I could have words that appear in a sequence, and each word would be inputted into a different cell, while the number of features of that cell would be the dimension of the word embedding.

Comment: @VivekSubramanian just edited my post to better clarify what I mean by "cell" and "features", thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the number of features, or dimension of your hidden state, $H$ can be greater than or less than the number of dimensions of your input $D$.

For instance, if you're doing classification, setting $H > D$ allows your model to generate new, derived features from your input.

On the other hand, if you're building an autoencoder, then the model will, in theory, be able to copy the input if all layers between the input and the output have dimension greater than or equal to $D$. The result does depend on your choice of activation function, however. If you choose a ReLU activation but some of your inputs are less than zero, for example, then it may not be possible to reconstruct your input exactly, certainly not with $D=H$ and even possibly if $D > H$. Moreover, pathological behavior has been observed in feedforward networks with $D=1$ and $H \gg D$ (see, for example, section 1.1 of [Trask et al. (2018)](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/8027-neural-arithmetic-logic-units.pdf)).

In computer vision, for compression or denoising autoencoders, people typically choose $H < D$ so that the autoencoder learns to represent the image using fewer features or with less noise.

I can't point you to specific examples, but I'm sure similar principles apply to other fields for tasks involving sequences.

Comment: picking up on your comment that "**_H_** > __*D*__" allows the model to generate new features, If the subsequent layers are to perform a bottleneck on the dimension of __*H*__ to a point where the encoder part of the AE ends with __*H*__ < __*D*__ and the decoder part picks up from there, is it reasonable to say that the AE is compressing the original input features plus additional features learned in the first layer of the AE (where __*H*__ > __*D*__)?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.